# Control Shape Gradient Properties via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find a means of controlling the Gradient fill properties of a 'shape' in Excel 2016.  I have 8 shapes (called Shape1-8) which will act as colour swatches for the gradient of a MASTER shape.  The positioning of each swatch (gradient stop) will (eventually) be controlled via either spinners / scrollbars. 
Couldn't find much online soo I turned to the good old 'Record Macro' whilst I tried to reverse engineer the functionality.  This is were the problems began...

So I constructed a simple 2 colour gradient, Black to White.

Then added a third colour, Red.

Moved the Red stop from default 50% to 83%

Then added a fourth colour, yellow

```vb
With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .BackColor.RGB = RGB(250, 250, 250)
        .TwoColorGradient msoGradientHorizontal, 1
End With

Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoTrue  'Added Red
Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoTrue  'Moved Red from 50% to 83%
Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoTrue  'Added Yellow
```

I was hoping to find a means to pull existing colour from Swatch Shape (1-8) to update the associated Gradient Stop (1-8) in the MASTER, like so....

```vb
...Shape("Master").Gradient1.backcolor.fill = ...Shape("Swatch1").Backcolor.fill
```

without having to code the RGB passing from the swatch controls

```vb
...Shape("Swatch1").BackColor.RGB = RGB(TextRed.value, TextGreen.value, TextBlue.value)
```

into

```vb
...Shape("Master").Gradient1.BackColor.RGB = RGB(TextRed.value, TextGreen.value, TextBlue.value)
```

Comment: What's your question? Why is using RGB a problem?

Comment: The issue is being able to control the gradient stops within a shape via VBA.  Basic two colour gradients with stops at 0% and 100% are fine, but add a third or fourth colour or move the position of the gradient stop and VBA only detected this as:  `Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoTrue`

Comment: This is only a problem because our internal IT/Cyber departments have had a crack down about internal bespoke software that's been developed.  I had previously had a WPS desktop version running perfectly but have now had to go low-tech with excel to have a GUI for editing and creating palette files for use with Infrared Thermography software.